# How to fill a Shape with pixel->color function in Java 2D?

Tags: java, java-2d

I have several [`Area`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html)s that I need to fill with a color gradient. I have a function that associates a pixel position with its color, like this:

```
(x,y) -> some RGBA color
```

My question is: **what part of the Java API would allow me to use such a function to fill my `Area`s?**

- I have looked into gradients in Java 2D, but I think they are too specific to achieve what I want (they don't accept a function like mine).
- I tried to understand the [`Paint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Paint.html)/[`Raster`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/Raster.html)/[`ColorModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/ColorModel.html) stuff, but it's still very blurry in my mind and I still don't understand if what I want can be represented by a `ColorModel`. I'm under the impression that the purpose of this class is not to associate a pixel position with its color, but a color representation to another representation, am I right on this?
- The only viable option I thought of is using a [`BufferedImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html), and use `setRGB()` on every pixel with my function's value. However, as it's a rectangle, I would have to generate transparent pixels when out of the bounds of my `Area`, and that might not be the best way regarding performance. **Would that be the right way to go, anyway?**

Are there some more appropriate solutions that I'm missing here?

*Note: I'm not looking for detailed implementation of a solution, I just want to go in the right direction* ;-)

Comment: That's indeed tricky (I tried to figure out something similar a while ago): WHO places the actual pixels (and HOW) is hidden unimaginably deep in the Swing painting pipeline, unfortunately. The first thing that came to my mind was your third approach, but as you mentioned: Thousands of `if(area.contains(pixel))` calls will kill performance. Could one solution be to simply fill a `BufferedImage` *completely* with the desired colors, and then paint this image using the given area as the `Graphics#setClip`? (Not sure about the performance here, but most likely better than manual tests...)

Comment: Can you post your full code please?

Comment: @Marco13 Indeed that would be a start, drawing a rectangle image, and then clip it to with the Shape of my area.

Comment: @explodingcreeperssss Have you read my question? I don't see how any code would be relevant here.

Comment: when you declare your Graphics2D, what do you call it? I want to give you the most specific answer I can.

Comment: @explodingcreeperssss The name of my variables is definitely not relevant, but if you must have it, my `Graphics2D` is called `g2d`... As I said, I don't need a full implemented solution, I just need advice on existing API I might have missed, or general ideas on how to deal with the problem.

Comment: @Marco13 Actually I wonder if `if(area.contains(pixel))` is more time-consuming than my function. My function includes division and squares, maybe logs too.. :( So maybe it's not worth calculating the color of every non-displayed pixel and clipping afterwards.

Comment: Whether `Area#contains` is time-consuming or not heavily depends on the "type" of the area: For a simple rectangle, it will be cheap. For a complex path that involves cubic curves etc. it will be expensive. In any case, if you wanted to optimize this part, you could convert it into a `Shape` and convert this shape into a *new* shape with a flattening `PathIterator` - this "simplifies" the shape, with a hardly noticable error, but can *dramatically* increase performance of some operations...

Comment: ... BTW: You did not say anything about the cost of your function originally. If it is really expensive, this may indeed be a trade-off between the function itself and the `Area#contains` calls. But here, some tests/"benchmarking" might be necessary. Maybe one can do some optimizations with bounding box tests or so, but this are considerations that are beyond the scope of this comment ;-)

Comment: @Marco13 All of my areas are already flat for now. No curves at all, only straight lines. You are right, when talking about performance, benchmarking is often necessary. In a way you answered my question when saying that `BufferedImage` is the way to go. How to optimize its use is another story ^^

Comment: I did not say that it is the way to go, but only suggested that it *for me* seemed as the only solution that can be implemented with reasonable effort (and without diving into the depths of the `SunGraphics2D` implementation - that's really a nasty piece of code...)

Comment: @Marco13 Indeed, you didn't say such a thing. But I've been looking for this kind of stuff for days now, and as nothing pops out from Google searches, StackOverflow, nor the Javadoc, there is probably no other not-overly-complicated solution to this problem ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was curious, and implemented the approach mentioned in the comment:

> Could one solution be to simply fill a BufferedImage completely with the desired colors, and then paint this image using the given area as the Graphics#setClip? (Not sure about the performance here, but most likely better than manual tests...)

The result is the following:

[image]

This example uses some "dummy" class

```
class ColorFunction
{
    int getColor(int x, int y) 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

that is backed by a randomly filled `BufferedImage`, just for this test. This function is transferred into a `BufferedImage` in the `paintComponent` method. In a "real" application case, this could and should be done somewhere else, maybe in some constructor, so that it has to be done only once, but this depends on how this should be used. However, then, the image is just painted, using the `Area` as the clipping shape of the `Graphics2D`.

It seems feasible, but I have not yet made any detailed performance tests.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.font.GlyphVector;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class CustomFillingTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        ColorFunction colorFunction = new ColorFunction();
        Area area = createTestArea();

        CustomFillingPanel customFillingPanel = 
            new CustomFillingPanel(colorFunction, area);
        f.getContentPane().add(customFillingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        f.setSize(400,200);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static Area createTestArea()
    {
        Font font = new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 120);
        final FontRenderContext fontRenderContext = 
            new FontRenderContext(null, true, true);
        GlyphVector glyphVector = font.createGlyphVector(
            fontRenderContext, "Test");
        Shape shape = glyphVector.getOutline(0,0);
        AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(40, 100);
        Area area = new Area(at.createTransformedShape(shape));
        return area;
    }




}



class ColorFunction
{
    private final BufferedImage bufferedImage;

    ColorFunction()
    {
        this.bufferedImage = createDummyImage(1000, 1000);
    }

    private static BufferedImage createDummyImage(int w, int h)
    {
        Random random = new Random(1);
        BufferedImage image = 
            new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics graphics = image.createGraphics();
        graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        for (int i=0; i<1000; i++)
        {
            int r = random.nextInt(255);
            int g = random.nextInt(255);
            int b = random.nextInt(255);
            Color c = new Color(r,g,b);
            int x = random.nextInt(w);
            int y = random.nextInt(h);
            int n = random.nextInt(w/10);
            graphics.setColor(c);
            graphics.fillRect(x,y,n,n);
        }
        graphics.dispose();
        return image;
    }

    int getColor(int x, int y)
    {
        int w = bufferedImage.getWidth();
        int h = bufferedImage.getHeight();
        return bufferedImage.getRGB(x%w, y%h);
    }
}


class CustomFillingPanel extends JPanel
{
    private final ColorFunction colorFunction;
    private final Area area;

    CustomFillingPanel(ColorFunction colorFunction, Area area)
    {
        this.colorFunction = colorFunction;
        this.area = area;
    }

    private static void paintIntoImage(
        ColorFunction colorFunction, BufferedImage bufferedImage)
    {
        int w = bufferedImage.getWidth();
        int h = bufferedImage.getHeight();
        for (int y=0; y<h; y++)
        {
            for (int x=0; x<w; x++)
            {
                int rgb = colorFunction.getColor(x, y);
                bufferedImage.setRGB(x, y, rgb);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Rectangle b = area.getBounds();
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = 
            new BufferedImage(b.width,  b.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        paintIntoImage(colorFunction, bufferedImage);

        g.setClip(area);
        g.drawImage(bufferedImage, b.x, b.y, null);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to implement such an experiment. It seems a rather clean approach, I haven't thought of better optimizations so far, but I think I'll have to benchmark it and compare. You should probably put the idea of your first comment in your answer, so that I can accept it for future readers ;-)